# ServerSignature is set to off, but still visible

Tags: apache2

I'm in the middle of apache2 hardening for a project I'm working on.

I've set the ServerSignature to Off and the ServerToken to Prod, but I still get the Server Info Listed on 404 and 403 pages.

restarted apache multiple times.

thankful for any tips to resolve the problem. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Typo `ServerTokens Prod` fixed the problem